# Oracle: splitting time range into days and calculation of duration

Tags: oracle

I'm developing code calculation service availability based on events, so I need to split events into daily "sub-events" and calculate duration of then.
So as input I have set of events like `(EVENT_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME)`:

```
'event1';2021-05-01 12:30;2021-05-01 13:00
'event2';2021-05-03 10:55;2021-05-05 12:01
```

As output I'd like to get `(EVENT_ID, DAY, DURATION_MINUTES)`:

```
'event1'; 2021-05-01; 30
'event2'; 2021-05-03; 785
'event2'; 2021-05-04; 1440
'event2'; 2021-05-05; 721
```

I can get it using procedures and cursor but this is not effective (the events database is quite big), so  is there a way to do it using oracle sql query ? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want a recursive query:

```sql
WITH days ( event_id, day, start_time, end_time ) AS (
  SELECT event_id,
         TRUNC( start_time ),
         start_time,
         end_time
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT event_id,
         day + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         start_time,
         end_time
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day + INTERVAL '1' DAY < end_time
)
SELECT event_id,
       day,
       ROUND(
         (
           LEAST(end_time, day + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
           - GREATEST(start_time, day)
         ) * 24 * 60
       ) AS duration_minutes
FROM   days
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( event_id, start_time, end_time ) AS
SELECT 'event1', DATE '2021-05-01' + INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2021-05-01' + INTERVAL '13:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'event2', DATE '2021-05-03' + INTERVAL '10:55' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2021-05-05' + INTERVAL '12:01' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EVENT_ID | DAY | DURATION_MINUTES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | event1 | 2021-05-01 | 30 |
> | event2 | 2021-05-03 | 785 |
> | event2 | 2021-05-04 | 1440 |
> | event2 | 2021-05-05 | 721 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7eccbfac037d20c306b278c3d28b626)*

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for sharing. I am curious about the size of the database of the OP and how the performance copes.

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle version is 12 or higher, you can use a lateral join (in any of several equivalent formulations/syntaxes) to make the query faster. For example (using the table set up in MT0's answer):

```
select event_id, day, round(1440 * duration_days) as duration_minutes
from   table_name cross join lateral
       ( select  trunc(start_time) + level - 1 as day,
                 case when level = 1 and connect_by_isleaf = 1
                                     then end_time - start_time
                      when level = 1 then 1 - (start_time - trunc(start_time))
                      when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then end_time - trunc(end_time)
                      else 1 end as duration_days
         from    dual
         connect by level <= 1 + trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time)
       )
where  duration_days != 0
order  by event_id, day
;
```

The `where` clause is used when the `end_time` is midnight (at the beginning of an otherwise "new" day); in that case, presumably, you don't want to include that "new day" in the output, with a duration of 0 minutes.

In the lateral view, `level = 1` corresponds to the first date in the interval, while `connect_by_isleaf = 1` is for the last date in the interval. A special calculation is made when the end_time and start_time are on the same date. The query computes the difference in days first, then converts to minutes. Note that date calculations aren't 100% precise; I used `round` so I don't get results like 33.9999999999938020 minutes. If the inputs are in `hh24:mi`, we know beforehand that the answer (in minutes) should be an integer, so `round` seems fine there.